# KDB - Compare value to value x rows back (deltas but going back x rows)

Tags: kdb

I have a table with Instrument, Time, Price

```
Instrument   Time                            Price
Stock x      2019.05.17D10:01:00.000000000   1.2
Stock x      2019.05.17D10:02:00.000000000   1.4
Stock x      2019.05.17D10:03:00.000000000   1.3
Stock x      2019.05.17D10:04:00.000000000   1.2
Stock x      2019.05.17D10:05:00.000000000   1.4
Stock x      2019.05.17D10:06:00.000000000   1.6
Stock x      2019.05.17D10:07:00.000000000   2.3
Stock x      2019.05.17D10:08:00.000000000   2.4
Stock x      2019.05.17D10:09:00.000000000   2.2
Stock x      2019.05.17D10:10:00.000000000   2.5
```

Then i want to compare the deltas price development over a running window, going x minutes back.

If i do something like

```
     newdata:({0,1_deltas x}(close))%(close) by Instrument from Table
```

I get the comparison going 1 row back. (1.2/1.4 // 1.4/1.3 // 1.3/1.2)

A:
I would like to do the deltas - but going back several rows.
Meaning with x=5 rows 1.2/1.6 // 1.4/2.3 // etc..

B:
If I lack minute data at some point - Deltas will not take into account the minutes difference (and price development would not be as easily comparable) - So i would like to know, how i can make a solution, that is not only comparing with x rows prior, but also specificly focused on the time difference, when going the comparison in hindsight.

Comment: For part B, what output/behaviour you are looking for?

Comment: For part B, you want to fill the data with the most recent price correct i.e if the price at 09:01 was 12 and the next price you had was 13 at 09:05 you would want everything in between to have a price of 12

Am I correct?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to purely base the look back on x rows, then you can use [xprev](https://code.kx.com/v2/ref/next/#xprev).

```
tab:([]sym:10#`MSFT;time:(2019.05.01D10:00:00.000000+/:00:01+til 10);price:(1.2;1.4;1.3;1.2;1.4;1.6;2.3;2.4;2.2;2.5))

//Can adjust the row lookback value
update diff:(lookback-price) from update lookback:{y xprev x}[;5] price by sym from tab
```

This should also account for Scenario B, as it will return a null which can be discarded from any price development calculations. However, if your data wasn't bucketed into 1-minute slots and you wanted to do a look back on time you will need to create some kind of window-join, a good example can be found here [Rolling window in multi groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49754101/rolling-window-in-multi-groups)